# Erro de java virtual machine em projeto xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, cross-platform

Tenho um projeto Android que roda normalmente. Porem criei um Cross Platform e está dando esse erro:

> Erro      Could not create the Java Virtual
>   Machine.  Autorizador.Android C:\Mobile\Autorizador\Autorizador\Autorizador.Android\COMPILETODALVIK

Tenho que fazer alguma configuração? Eu coloquei na configuração do projeto Android 1Gb no Hearp do java, seguindo uma orientação.

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui depois.
http://mhbs.com.br/2017/01/17/dica-como-resolver-o-erro-could-not-create-the-java-virtual-machine-em-xamarin/

Comment: @PauloHDSousa, acho que foi no momento em eu fui colocar o tamanho do Heap, eu fiz assim 1Gb e deveria ser 1G apenas, nas propriedades do Android. Fiz essa correção e não deu mais o erro. Vou ficar atento e ler o seu link com certeza. Ainda não respondi, esperando ver se dá pau. Caso continue assim, eu respondo.